# Dividing a disk of diameter 1 into pieces of smaller diameter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, dissection

Let $F$ be an arbitrary bounded set on the plane, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let's define $d_n(F)$ as the minimum diameter one can ensure when cutting a set $F$ into $n$ pieces.

So, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940531/generalizing-the-borsuk-problem-how-much-can-we-shrink-a-planar-set-of-diameter/4045557#4045557) is a discussion of the value $d_n(F)$ for an arbitrary set of diameter 1.

I decided to consider $d_n$ for a circle of unit diameter D.
It is quite simple to understand the values of $d_n(D)$ for $n \leqslant 7$ and they are calculated in [SCY, page 96-98](*[Geometrical estimations and combinatorial geometry problems](http://ilib.mccme.ru/djvu/bib-mat-kr/shk-13.djvu)*): $d_1(D) = d_2(D) = 1, d_3(D)= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}, d_4(D) = \frac{ \sqrt 2}{2}, d_5(D) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{5})$, and $d_6(D) = d_7(D) = \frac{1}{2}$. I also can prove that $d_8 (D) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{7})$, this is also not difficult (there will be 1 set to cover the center and 7 to cover the border of disk)

[image]

But for $d_{9}(D)$ I don't know precise value. I know that $0.3826... = \sin(\frac{\pi}{8}) \leqslant d_9(D) \leqslant \frac{\sqrt{7} - 1}{3\sqrt{2}} = 0.3879...$.

The lower estimate is correct, because otherwise, for $x < \sin(\frac{\pi}{8})$, there are not enough 8 sets to cover the boundary of the disk,  so the set that covers the center will have a diameter of at least $0.5$.

The upper bound is correct from [this picture](https://www.geogebra.org/m/dprypban):
[image]

The dashed lines indicate the segments where the diameter is reached.

I think that this partition is optimal, but I don't yet understand how to prove it strictly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The source you linked to goes to a 384-page book. If $d_1, \dots, d_7$ are in it, can you give the page number?